# Display date in arabic in this format 'Wednesday, May 22, 2013'

Tags: c#, date

I have a multilingual website and I need to show the date in this format `Wednesday, May 22, 2013`. I use following line of code to display dates

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("D");
```

That doesn't work when I use this along with Culture info

It then shows me dates in this format `مايو 2013,22`

How can I show date in arabic in format `year, date month day`

I am not sure why `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("D");` is not able to convert to arabic date with weekdays

UPDATE : this works `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the format explicitly:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

This will output, for example:

```
Wednesday, May 22, 2013
```

A lowercase 'd' stands for the day, two 'd's for the day with a zero in front if applicable, three 'd's for the abbreviation of the name of the day and four 'd's for the complete name of the day. The same applies to the months with a capital 'M' (lowercase 'm' are minutes!).

Comment: This one :`DateTime.Now.ToString("dd dddd , MMMM, yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `CultureInfo` class to convert date formats in different languages.

```
using System.Globalization;    
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));
```